# python: i can't seem to pull info out of html

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request, urllib

Im having loads of trouble pin pointing what i need to specify to pull these parts out of this html from a website. I have no problem if i hard code the html in the script but when i try to pull the info from the website i get this error below.

HARDCODED SCRIPT WORKING -

```
html = "" #hardcoded the html form site
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
div = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"fp-root"})  
productid = [x['data-product-id'] for x in div]
print(productid)
```

CODE -

```
session = requests.Session()
product_url = 'http:/randomsite.com/something.html'
response = session.get(product_url)

soup1 = BeautifulSoup(response.url, 'lxml')
div1 = soup1.find_all("div",{"class":"fp-root"})  
all_sizes1 = [x['data-product-id'] for x in div1]
print(all_sizes1)
```

ERROR -

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py:282: UserWarning: "http://randomsite.com/something.html" looks like a URL. Beautiful Soup is not an HTTP client. You should probably use an HTTP client like requests to get the document behind the URL, and feed that document to Beautiful Soup.
  ' that document to Beautiful Soup.' % decoded_markup
```

So I tried to use urllib

and i am getting a 503 error no clue why I'm having this much problem but I'm lost, no idea if I'm getting further from the conclusion or if I'm on the right path. any help and explanation would be greatly appreciated.

CODE -

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib.request
import os
os.system('clear')


url = urllib.request.urlopen('http:/randomsite.com/something.html')
pull = url.read()
print(pull)

soup = BeautifulSoup(pull, 'lxml')
div = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"fp-root"})  
all_sizes = [x['data-product-id'] for x in div]
print(all_sizes)
```

ERROR -

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable
```

HTML -

```
<div class="atg_store_sizePicker size-label">
    <label class="atg_store_pickerLabel">
    Size
    </label>

      <div class="fp-root fp-align" data-product-id="505316967"></div>

      <!-- Check if the fit predictor is enabled for current site or not -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/fitpredictor.js"></script>


    <span id="fp-data" data-securitystatus="0" data-productid="505316967" data-customerid="678380871"
        data-market="US" data-language="en" data-shippingcountry="US"
        data-page="pdp" data-brand="adidas" data-productname="Men's Suede Gazelle Sneakers " data-category="BNY-mens-sneakers" data-minprice="150.0"
        data-maxprice="150.0" data-color="CREAM"></span>
        <input type="hidden" id="fp_allSizes" value='["6 M","7 M","7.5 M","8 M","8.5 M","9 M","9.5 M","10 M","10.5 M","11 M","11.5 M","12 M","13 M"]' />
        <input type="hidden" id="fp_availableSizes" value='["6 M","7 M","7.5 M","8 M","8.5 M","9 M","9.5 M","10 M","10.5 M","11 M","11.5 M","13 M"]' />

    <span class="selector">

            <a class=" atg_store_oneSize sizePicker " data-productid="505316967"  data-skuid="00505053169686" data-onhand-quantity="1" 
                      data-onorder-quantity="0" data-availabilitystatus="1000" data-sale-price="150.0" 
                      data-list-price="150.0" data-on-sale="false" data-atp="1" data-isprivate="0" 
                      data-expected-delivery-month="" data-gwp="0" data-vendorcolor="CREAM" data-currentcommerceitemid="" 
                      data-product-current-site="BNY" data-is-ap-enabled-for-sku ="true"  data-is-ap-enabled-for-product="true" href="javascript:void(0)">
             6 M
            </a>

            <a class=" atg_store_oneSize sizePicker " data-productid="505316967"  data-skuid="00505053169693" data-onhand-quantity="1" 
                      data-onorder-quantity="0" data-availabilitystatus="1000" data-sale-price="150.0" 
                      data-list-price="150.0" data-on-sale="false" data-atp="1" data-isprivate="0" 
                      data-expected-delivery-month="" data-gwp="0" data-vendorcolor="CREAM" data-currentcommerceitemid="" 
                      data-product-current-site="BNY" data-is-ap-enabled-for-sku ="true"  data-is-ap-enabled-for-product="true" href="javascript:void(0)">
             7 M
            </a>

            <a class=" atg_store_oneSize sizePicker " data-productid="505316967"  data-skuid="00505053169785" data-onhand-quantity="1" 
                      data-onorder-quantity="0" data-availabilitystatus="1000" data-sale-price="150.0" 
                      data-list-price="150.0" data-on-sale="false" data-atp="1" data-isprivate="0" 
                      data-expected-delivery-month="" data-gwp="0" data-vendorcolor="CREAM" data-currentcommerceitemid="" 
                      data-product-current-site="BNY" data-is-ap-enabled-for-sku ="true"  data-is-ap-enabled-for-product="true" href="javascript:void(0)">
             7.5 M
            </a>

            <a class=" atg_store_oneSize sizePicker " data-productid="505316967"  data-skuid="00505053169709" data-onhand-quantity="1" 
                      data-onorder-quantity="0" data-availabilitystatus="1000" data-sale-price="150.0" 
                      data-list-price="150.0" data-on-sale="false" data-atp="1" data-isprivate="0" 
                      data-expected-delivery-month="" data-gwp="0" data-vendorcolor="CREAM" data-currentcommerceitemid="" 
                      data-product-current-site="BNY" data-is-ap-enabled-for-sku ="true"  data-is-ap-enabled-for-product="true" href="javascript:void(0)">
             8 M
            </a>

            <a class=" atg_store_oneSize sizePicker " data-productid="505316967"  data-skuid="00505053169792" data-onhand-quantity="2" 
                      data-onorder-quantity="0" data-availabilitystatus="1000" data-sale-price="150.0" 
                      data-list-price="150.0" data-on-sale="false" data-atp="2" data-isprivate="0" 
                      data-expected-delivery-month="" data-gwp="0" data-vendorcolor="CREAM" data-currentcommerceitemid="" 
                      data-product-current-site="BNY" data-is-ap-enabled-for-sku ="true"  data-is-ap-enabled-for-product="true" href="javascript:void(0)">
             8.5 M
            </a>

            <a class=" atg_store_oneSize sizePicker " data-productid="505316967"  data-skuid="00505053169716" data-onhand-quantity="5" 
                      data-onorder-quantity="0" data-availabilitystatus="1000" data-sale-price="150.0" 
                      data-list-price="150.0" data-on-sale="false" data-atp="5" data-isprivate="0" 
                      data-expected-delivery-month="" data-gwp="0" data-vendorcolor="CREAM" data-currentcommerceitemid="" 
                      data-product-current-site="BNY" data-is-ap-enabled-for-sku ="true"  data-is-ap-enabled-for-product="true" href="javascript:void(0)">
             9 M
            </a>

            <a class=" atg_store_oneSize sizePicker " data-productid="505316967"  data-skuid="00505053169808" data-onhand-quantity="3" 
                      data-onorder-quantity="0" data-availabilitystatus="1000" data-sale-price="150.0" 
                      data-list-price="150.0" data-on-sale="false" data-atp="3" data-isprivate="0" 
                      data-expected-delivery-month="" data-gwp="0" data-vendorcolor="CREAM" data-currentcommerceitemid="" 
                      data-product-current-site="BNY" data-is-ap-enabled-for-sku ="true"  data-is-ap-enabled-for-product="true" href="javascript:void(0)">
             9.5 M
            </a>

            <a class=" atg_store_oneSize sizePicker " data-productid="505316967"  data-skuid="00505053169723" data-onhand-quantity="4" 
                      data-onorder-quantity="0" data-availabilitystatus="1000" data-sale-price="150.0" 
                      data-list-price="150.0" data-on-sale="false" data-atp="4" data-isprivate="0" 
                      data-expected-delivery-month="" data-gwp="0" data-vendorcolor="CREAM" data-currentcommerceitemid="" 
                      data-product-current-site="BNY" data-is-ap-enabled-for-sku ="true"  data-is-ap-enabled-for-product="true" href="javascript:void(0)">
             10 M
            </a>

            <a class=" atg_store_oneSize sizePicker " data-productid="505316967"  data-skuid="00505053169815" data-onhand-quantity="3" 
                      data-onorder-quantity="0" data-availabilitystatus="1000" data-sale-price="150.0" 
                      data-list-price="150.0" data-on-sale="false" data-atp="3" data-isprivate="0" 
                      data-expected-delivery-month="" data-gwp="0" data-vendorcolor="CREAM" data-currentcommerceitemid="" 
                      data-product-current-site="BNY" data-is-ap-enabled-for-sku ="true"  data-is-ap-enabled-for-product="true" href="javascript:void(0)">
             10.5 M
            </a>

            <a class=" atg_store_oneSize sizePicker " data-productid="505316967"  data-skuid="00505053169730" data-onhand-quantity="3" 
                      data-onorder-quantity="0" data-availabilitystatus="1000" data-sale-price="150.0" 
                      data-list-price="150.0" data-on-sale="false" data-atp="3" data-isprivate="0" 
                      data-expected-delivery-month="" data-gwp="0" data-vendorcolor="CREAM" data-currentcommerceitemid="" 
                      data-product-current-site="BNY" data-is-ap-enabled-for-sku ="true"  data-is-ap-enabled-for-product="true" href="javascript:void(0)">
             11 M
            </a>

            <a class=" atg_store_oneSize sizePicker " data-productid="505316967"  data-skuid="00505053169822" data-onhand-quantity="1" 
                      data-onorder-quantity="0" data-availabilitystatus="1000" data-sale-price="150.0" 
                      data-list-price="150.0" data-on-sale="false" data-atp="1" data-isprivate="0" 
                      data-expected-delivery-month="" data-gwp="0" data-vendorcolor="CREAM" data-currentcommerceitemid="" 
                      data-product-current-site="BNY" data-is-ap-enabled-for-sku ="true"  data-is-ap-enabled-for-product="true" href="javascript:void(0)">
             11.5 M
            </a>

            <a class=" atg_store_oneSize disabled-size sizePicker " data-productid="505316967"  data-skuid="00505053169747" data-onhand-quantity="0" 
                      data-onorder-quantity="0" data-availabilitystatus="1001" data-sale-price="150.0" 
                      data-list-price="150.0" data-on-sale="false" data-currentcommerceitemid="" data-isprivate="0" 
                      data-atp="0" data-gwp="0" data-vendorcolor="CREAM" 
                      data-product-current-site="BNY" href="javascript:void(0)">
             12 M
            </a>

            <a class=" atg_store_oneSize sizePicker " data-productid="505316967"  data-skuid="00505053169754" data-onhand-quantity="2" 
                      data-onorder-quantity="0" data-availabilitystatus="1000" data-sale-price="150.0" 
                      data-list-price="150.0" data-on-sale="false" data-atp="2" data-isprivate="0" 
                      data-expected-delivery-month="" data-gwp="0" data-vendorcolor="CREAM" data-currentcommerceitemid="" 
                      data-product-current-site="BNY" data-is-ap-enabled-for-sku ="true"  data-is-ap-enabled-for-product="true" href="javascript:void(0)">
             13 M
            </a>

    </span>    
  </div>
```

Comment: You need `soup1 = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')` in your `CODE`.

Comment: I needed to send headers was my problem but thanks @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ